# How to remove the AbsoluteLayout id?

Tags: java, android, absolutelayout

why statement `android:id="@+id/"` keep on appearing everytime I wanted to run my app ? Is there a way to remove it ? Thanks

```
 <AbsoluteLayout
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/">
```

**Error**

```
Error:(16, 21) Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'id' with value '@+id/').
```

I understand that we need to set an id if we want to use it. If I remove it and run, the app still working.But when I run second time, it appears again.

Comment: AbsoluteLayout. This class was deprecated in API level 3.
Use FrameLayout, RelativeLayout or a custom layout instead.
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The at sign (@) is required when you're referring to any resource
>   object from XML. It is followed by the resource type (id in this
>   case), a slash, then the resource name .
>
> Resource Objects
>
> A resource object is a unique integer name that's associated with an
>   app resource, such as a bitmap, layout file, or string.
>
> Every resource has a corresponding resource object defined in your
>   project's gen/R.java file. You can use the object names in the R class
>   to refer to your resources, such as when you need to specify a string
>   value for the android:hint attribute. You can also create arbitrary
>   resource IDs that you associate with a view using the android:id
>   attribute, which allows you to reference that view from other code.
>
> The SDK tools generate the R.java file each time you compile your app.
>   You should never modify this file by hand.
>
> For more information, read the guide to Providing Resources. The plus
>   sign (+) before the resource type is needed only when you're defining
>   a resource ID for the first time.

You have to set ***id***

```
android:id="@+id/Your_id
```

> +id Plus sing tells android to add or create a new id in Resources.

Finally

```
<AbsoluteLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Your_id">
```

Comment: if not need then remove `android:id="@+id/Your_id"`

Comment: But when i run the app second time, it appears again

Comment: Okat At first remove this line ,Then `clean & rebuild (Restart & Sync)` your project

Comment: Please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969193/why-cannot-add-new-list-in-listview?noredirect=1#comment55695373_33969193